# Novos Certificado da Apple só funcionam com XCode 11?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple, mac

O Site de Desenvolvedores da Apple ganhou novo layout, e, aparentemente, novas funções. Eu criei um Certificado hoje e, ao invés de iOS Distribution, está aparecendo apenas Distribution e na frente "For use in Xcode 11 ou later".

Até adicionei na Keychain do Mac, mas simplesmente não funciona. Isso quer dizer que sem o Xcode 11 NÃO é mais possível publicar na Apple Store?

**Edit 1:**

Estou usando macOS Mojave 10.14.5 e Xcode 10.2.1 (o Sistema não encontra o xcode 11 para atualizar).

**Edit 2:**

Dentro do Xcode, eu conseguir criar um novo certificado durante o processo de Archive. O certificado em questão, gerado automaticamente, resolveu meu problema, e apareceu no Site sem a mensagem de funcionamento apenas para xcode 11, mas ainda assim não entendi por que esse tipo de certificado não pode ser gerado pelo site. Não achei nenhuma informação oficial sobre o assunto, se alguém tiver para complementar.